# Foreign Key Excluyente

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta, tengo tres tablas, la tercera recibe las foreing key de las dos primeras, pero
necesito saber como hacer que sea excluyente, es decir que si recibe
la FK de una tabla no requiera de la segunda(o algo parecido), graciass!

```
asiento(id, debe, haber, id_cuenta o id_sub_cuenta)

cuenta(id, nombre, saldo)
sub_cuenta(id, nombre, saldo, id_cuenta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,
no sé si te sirva, pero una opción sería agregar los dos campos sin que sean obligatorios y validar por medio de código antes de registrar que se guarde alguna de las dos, y a la hora de consultar filtras por las dos.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente, lo que pretendes con la tabla `sub_cuenta`, lo puedes modelar mediante una relación consigo misma de la tabla `cuenta`, añadiendo un campo del tipo `id_cuenta_padre`. Una vez modelado así, tu problema desparece, pues únicamente registras un `id_cuenta` en `asiento`:

```
asiento ( id_asiento, debe, haber, id_cuenta )
cuenta (id_cuenta, nombre, saldo, id_cuenta_padre )
```